# Firebase and React JS contact form working in firefox but not in chrome

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I created a contact me page for my portfolio.
My contact.js file -

```
import { db } from "../firebase";

const Contact = () => {
    const [name, setName] = useState("");
    const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
    const [message, setMessaage] = useState("");

    const [loader, setLoader] = useState(false);

    const handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        setLoader(true);
        
        db.collection('contacts').add({
            name:name,
            email:email,
            message:message,
        })
        .then(() => {
            alert("Thanks for dropping a message")
            setLoader(false);
        })
        .catch(error =>{
            alert(error.message);
            setLoader(false);
        });

        setName('');
        setEmail('');
        setMessaage('');
    }

    return(
        <div>
            <div id="contact">
                <div className="container contact-form pt-5 pb-5">
                    <div className="contact-image">
                        <img src={require('../images/message.png')} className="rounded-circle mx-auto img-fluid d-block" style={{ width: "200px", height: "200px" }} alt="" />
                    </div>
                    <form id="contactForm" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                        <h3 className="mb-3" style={{textAlign: "center"}}><b>Drop a Message</b></h3>
                        <div className="alert">Your message has been sent</div>
                        <div className="row justify-content-md-center">
                            <div className="col-md-6">
                                <div className="form-group">
                                    <input 
                                        placeholder="Name"
                                        value={name}
                                        onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)}
                                        style={{ backgroundColor:'#d9d9d9' }}
                                    />
                                </div>
                                <div><p></p></div>
                                <div className="form-group">
                                    <input 
                                        placeholder="Email"
                                        value={email}
                                        onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
                                        style={{ backgroundColor:'#d9d9d9' }}
                                    />
                                </div>
                                <div><p></p></div>
                                {/* <div className="form-group">
                                    <input type="text" name="phone" className="form-control" placeholder="Phone Number" id="phone" />
                                </div> */}
                                <div className="form-group">
                                    <textarea 
                                        placeholder="Message"
                                        value={message}
                                        onChange={(e) => setMessaage(e.target.value)}
                                    style={{ width: "100%", height: "150px", backgroundColor:'#d9d9d9' }}></textarea>
                                </div>
                                <div><p></p></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <div className="form-group" style={{textAlign:"center"}}>
                                <button type="submit" name="submit" className="btn btn-primary" style={{background : loader ? "#ccc" : "rgb(2, 2, 10)"}}>Send Message</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
            {/* <Footer /> */}
        </div>
    )
};

export default Contact;
```

My firebase.js file -

```
// Import the functions you need from the SDKs you need
import firebase from "firebase/compat/app";
import 'firebase/compat/firestore';
// TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
// https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries

var firebaseApp = firebase.initializeApp({
    apiKey: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_API_KEY,
    authDomain: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN,
    projectId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
    storageBucket: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET,
    messagingSenderId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
    appId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_APP_ID
});

var db = firebaseApp.firestore();

firebase.firestore().settings({ experimentalForceLongPolling: true, merge:true });

export { db };
```

I'm able to submit the form successfully in Mozzila Firefox browser, but My form doesn't get submitted in Google Chrome.
Error showed in console -
GET https://firestore.googleapis.com/google.firestore.v1.Firestore/Write/channel?VER=8&database=projects--------------------------------- net::ERR_ABORTED 400
react_devtools_backend.js:2655
[2023-04-05T09:11:41.516Z]  @firebase/firestore: Firestore (9.18.0): WebChannelConnection RPC 'Write' stream 0x3262790f transport errored: Jd {type: 'c', target: X, g: X, defaultPrevented: false, status: 1}

In network tab -
Call that goes - Request URL: https://firestore.googleapis.com/google.firestore.v1.Firestore/Write/channel?VER=8&database=projects%2Fportfolio-729d6%2Fdatabases%2F(default)&RID=64400&CVER=22&X-HTTP-Session-Id=gsessionid&zx=aatzxd2k&t=1
Request Method: POST
Status Code: 200
Remote Address: 64.233.189.95:443
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin

Response tab output - 51
[[0,["c","l1GkbYQ2N42-w-bVk7aWqg","",8,12,30000]]]

then next -
Request URL: https://firestore.googleapis.com/google.firestore.v1.Firestore/Write/channel?VER=8&database=projects%2Fportfolio-729d6%2Fdatabases%2F(default)&RID=rpc&SID=l1Gkb42-w-bVk7aWqg&CI=1&AID=0&TYPE=xmlhttp&zx=7b51un7griwb&t=1
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 400
Remote Address: 64.233.189.95:443
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin

response tab output - response tab is empty
[image: Image showing response as empty]

Please help

Comment: What is the actual response body for that 400 status? Use your browser's dev-tools _Network_ panel to inspect it

Comment: A recommendation... drop the _compat_, bite the bullet and use the modular syntax for Firebase v9. You'll find examples and documentation easier to find

Comment: Hi, have updated the question with network tab stuff, please check

Comment: I think you missed the part where you were supposed to find the response body. In the _Network_ panel, select the request with the 400 status and open the `Response` tab

Comment: for post - response tab - 51
[[0,["c","l1GkbYQ2N42-w-bVk7aWqg","",8,12,30000]]]

Comment: for get method which is coming back - response is empty

Comment: [Edit] your question to provide details. Also, check your browser extensions. If you have any enabled in Chrome, try disabling them

Comment: have updated the post, please check